# How to manually drain a free standing water tank (washing machine) into bucket(s)?

Tags: water, drain

Since our washing machine's filter was clogged, I had to drain it manually via emergency drain.

As the emergency drain is a very short (about 1 inch) and thin tube located about 1 inch from the floor, and I don't have any low wide receptacles, I had to use tilted [cooking pan](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fqph.fs.quoracdn.net%2Fmain-qimg-0ae94511d94de5cad4df2bcd48752241-c&f=1&nofb=1).

That worked, but it held only a small amount of water before I had to tip pan into bucket, due to the drain located so low. So I had to spend quite some time tipping every half a minute or so.

### This made me think, what would be a not very convoluted way to drain straight into a bucket, whose walls are much higher than the 1 inch above floor, where drain is located?

Of course, in addition to the drain location, the drain pipe itself is very short so I would need some connection to a larger tube in order to even reach any bucket (or just about anything beside the pan held right at the machine).

Since the drain is just a rubber tube without any connector at the end, I figured I could try getting a slightly larger diameter tube and use some waterproof duct tape, after sliding it over the drain. But that is already a bit convoluted since the drain pipe is so short.

That still doesn't answer the question how to drain from lower to a higher location. I thought I could buy one of those small pumps that can be used with an electric drill. Would that be a good way to do it?

Edit: the machine is  standing in a place which can't really be accessed from sides or back, and moving it is also a major hassle, as the top is quite near staircase bottom, so can't even tip it much (as suggested by some web advice).

Comment: Are you familiar with siphoning? That won't get what's behind the drum screen, but it'll get the bulk of the water out.

Comment: Our discharge hose comes out of the bottom of the machine in the back we used that hose into a bucket for most of ours then used that filter drain for the last few pans of water. I built a shelf for them to sit on next , had to extend the drain but next time this happens we will be ready, my wife likes them up the 12” now I have to make drawers , me and my big mouth.

Comment: If you have a wet and dry shop vac, that works well. On mine, the vacuum hose fits perfectly over the end of the drain hose, and produces enough suction to empty the drum.